# Ruby on Rails Plugins with netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, windows-xp, netbeans-6.9

In net beans 6.9.1 on windows rails plug-ins just simply don't work.
they wont even install from the command line, has anyone ever seen this before.

I am using git for windows and when I run.

```
ruby script\plugin install http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda.git/
```

in the base directory of my app I get.

```
Permission denied -- script/plugin (LoadError)
```

I have made sure the directory is readable, so I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running as Administrator?  The fact that your account has administrative privileges is not the same as running a ruby script as Administrator.

Comment: I tried it that way, but I get the same error.Even after changing the permissions.